# Java Save File Bug

Tags: java

sorry if this is a simple question, but i'm newbie in Java programming and can't deal with one problem with Java Save File Bug.. Bug is that, sometimes it saves and loads values without errors, some times it shows me error and still loads. But sometimes savefile wont work.

Error That I get :

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Clicker.ClickerGame.LoadFile(ClickerGame.java:2479)
at Clicker.mainClass.main(mainClass.java:27)
```

My Main (Starter Class) :

```
package Clicker;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class mainClass {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

            ClickerGame CG = new ClickerGame();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("CarCollectionarV1");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            CG.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());

            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setResizable(true);
            frame.setSize(1000, 700);

            CG.LoadFile();

            boolean GameLoop = true;
            while(GameLoop){
            CG.refresh();
            CG.SaveFile();
            }           

     }
}
```

ClickerGame class (Where are SaveFile and LoadFile functions):

```
  public void SaveFile(){
        try{
            File SaveFile = new File("SaveFile.sav");
            if(!SaveFile.exists()) {
                SaveFile.createNewFile();
            } 
            FileOutputStream saveFileSub = new FileOutputStream(SaveFile);
            ObjectOutputStream save = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFileSub);

            save.writeObject(CarMain.main);
            save.writeObject(Box.boxes);
            save.writeObject(CarFrame.frames);
            save.writeObject(Part.parts);
            save.writeObject(CarsLv1.cars);
            save.writeObject(CarsLv2.cars);
            save.writeObject(CarsLv3.cars);
            save.writeObject(CarsLv4.cars);
            save.writeObject(CarsLv5.cars);
            save.writeObject(CarsLv6.cars);
            save.writeObject(CarsLv7.cars);
            save.writeObject(CarsLv8.cars);
            save.writeObject(CarsLv9.cars);
            save.writeObject(CarsLv10.cars);

            save.close();
            }
            catch(Exception exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public void LoadFile(){
    try{
        File SaveFile = new File("SaveFile.sav");
        if(!SaveFile.exists()) {
            SaveFile.createNewFile();
        } 
        FileInputStream SaveFileSub = new FileInputStream(SaveFile);
        ObjectInputStream load = new ObjectInputStream(SaveFileSub);

        CarMain.main = (Integer[]) load.readObject();
        Box.boxes = (Integer[]) load.readObject();
        CarFrame.frames = (Integer[]) load.readObject();
        Part.parts = (Integer[]) load.readObject();
        CarsLv1.cars = (String[]) load.readObject();
        CarsLv2.cars = (String[]) load.readObject();
        CarsLv3.cars = (String[]) load.readObject();
        CarsLv4.cars = (String[]) load.readObject();
        CarsLv5.cars = (String[]) load.readObject();
        CarsLv6.cars = (String[]) load.readObject();
        CarsLv7.cars = (String[]) load.readObject();
        CarsLv8.cars = (String[]) load.readObject();
        CarsLv9.cars = (String[]) load.readObject();
        CarsLv10.cars = (String[]) load.readObject();

        load.close();
        }
        catch(Exception exc){
        exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

Comment: Side note on code quality: it seems that you already learned about the concept of arrays ... if so: then apply it to your "CarLvxx" fields. Given variables names ..1, ..2, ... and then having explicit code to handle them is simply super-bad, and should never be done. Besides: dont abbreviate within names. There is no point in saving a few characters while typing; as it makes reading source code harder each time one has to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You loadFile method is reading more than the file content. That's what an EOFException (End of File exception) is.

In your IDE, where you can see the line numbers, you'll be able to tell exactly at what point you overread: it's line 2479 in your ClickerGame class (see the stacktrace of the error)

If I were to guess, you are loading the file before saving it: since your loadfile creates the file if it's not there, you'll create an empty file which content then you try to read.

Comment: Yes, I first load, savefile (My thought is that : When first time, app launches, it creates new file, but if file exists, it loads objects). I know what line it is, but i can't figure out. When i was writing this question, I had this error. I went smoke, and didn't change anything in code, and now it again works. Started application 5 times, all times all loaded. Tried it again after 3minutes and again error. Why that?

Comment: To read from a file there must be something in the file. When you create the file, it's empty. If you try to read from an empty file (or from a position where there is nothing left to read), you'll get this error. If you want this to work, don't create the file in the load method. Do "if (fileExists) { read ;}" . What you have now is "if (!fileExists) {create} read no matter what";